# Ionic Cordova Android build fetches cordova-android 9 instead of 10

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have updated my Ionic Cordova project on my development machine to use cordova-android 10, via:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@latest
```

After this I have the following in my `package.json`:

```
"cordova-android": "^10.1.1",
```

I've updated build tools and sdk etc in Android Studio, do my build and all works fine.

Now, I check in my source, and do the same Android Studio updates on my Mac.

However, now when I do the same build (on the Mac), I see the message:

```
> cordova platform add android --save
  Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^9.0.0
```

And also it has updated my `package.json` back to "cordova-android": "9.1.0".

My question is, why could it do this, instead of fetching the `10.1.1` as is dictated in my package.json?

Comment: Run command: `ionic cordova platform add android@10.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

First, check the version of your android platform by using this command
`cordova platform`

You should see the version 9.x.x

Then run the following command
`cordova platform add android@10.1.1`

Re execute
`cordova platform`

You will see the version 10.1.1

That's it